# IdnMapping.GetAscii method in .NET C# not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, ascii, idn

When I call IdnMapping.GetAscii(http://президент.рф/)
I am getting result xn--http://-5ggibum1ewap2b.xn--/-4tbm
which is not correct.

I don't know where is the problem ? Is this method works as expected in C# ?
When I copy paste same url in Google Chrome which auto converts this into 
http://xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domain names do not include the protocol prefix.  Remove `http://` and the trailing backslash to get the exact same result.

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var map = new System.Globalization.IdnMapping();
        Console.WriteLine(map.GetAscii("президент.рф"));
    }
```

Output:

> xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai

Comment: Do you know may I call this same method on non IDN domain names as well ?